# ProvidesKey<T> in GWT

Tags: gwt

In GWT documentation in [this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#Selection_Data_Paging) article in "Keys" section said that `ProvidesKey<T>` allow us to identify the DTO object in cell list or cell table. Also there is a code sample that demonstrate that(they modify the contact and says that selection remains on that contact because they have provided a `keyProvider`).

```
Contact sarah = CONTACTS.get(3);
    selectionModel.setSelected(sarah, true);

    // Modify the name of the contact.
    sarah.name = "Sara";
```

But it also works without `keyprovider`. So the question is for what purposes we use `ProvidesKey` interface and why? At that example we can do the same without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default implementation without a key provider uses equals().

Key providers become essential when you replace one object with another instance representing the same "entity", *and* with different content (so equals() wouldn't work); such as when retrieving an updated version from the server.